# The method include is undefined in mongodb java

Tags: java, mongodb

I am using MongoDB shell version 3.6.3 and trying to perform a query(from JAVA) of the type :

```
SELECT _id, ressort, date from sample WHERE ressort != "A".
```

My piece of code is :

```
MongoClient mongo = new MongoClient("localhost", 27017);
MongoDatabase database = mongo.getDatabase("local");
MongoCollection<Document> collection = database.getCollection("sample");
FindIterable<Document> findIterable = collection.find(ne("ressort","A")).projection(include("ressort", "date"));
```

Eclipse is giving an error

> The method include(String, String) is undefined for the type App".

What to do?

I have already done the static import for Filter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `include` method is a static helper method from the class `com.mongodb.client.model.Projections`. Check your imports again.

[Here](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.6/builders) you can find the documentation of all the helpers.

Answer (score 1):

In my case I had to include the import as said by @cbartosiak and then I had to call the static method preceed by **Projections** to be recognized by my ID (Eclipse)

```
MongoClient mongo = new MongoClient("localhost", 27017);
MongoDatabase database = mongo.getDatabase("local");
MongoCollection<Document> collection = database.getCollection("sample");
FindIterable<Document> findIterable = collection.find(ne("ressort","A")).projection(Projections.include("ressort", "date"));
```